# Linq query, nested child objects in where, entity framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, nested, where-clause

I have the following Entity Framework model which i am retrieving a number of marketing_campaign entities. A Marketing campaign can have multiple groups and each group can have multiple stores.
[image]

What i need to be able to do is select all marketing campaigns for a particular StoreId. I know how to do the query for a single nested entity e.g. `Groups.SelectMany(n => n.StoresInGroups).Where(s=>s.StoreId == 2);` but not sure how to nest it deep enough to get the desired result.

Edit: Clearer picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var context = new context(); // init your context here
var query = 
    from sig in context.Store.Single(p=>p.StoreId = 2).StoresInGroup //filter out by particular toreId        
    from grp in sig.Group.Marketing_Groups
    from mc in grp.MarketingCampaign
    select mc;
```